# jQuery Flash Words

Tags: jquery, timeout, each, flashing

I'm trying to take a sentence and go through flashing the words, and the last word fade out, for a longer period.

For some reason it's only doing the last string in the array.

Thanks for your time : )

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7vy5sgk/)

```
<script>
    $(function() {

    //take sentence
      var lines = [
        'Apples are red',
        'Sky is blue',
        'Grass is green'
      ];
    //set index
    var i = 0;

    showLinesHelper();

    function showLinesHelper()  {
    //take line and split into words
      words = lines[i].split(' ');
      $.each(words, function(k, v)  {
    //take each word and flash
        if(k != words.length)  {
    //if not last word
          setTimeout(function()  {
    //display word into class
            $('.words').html(v);
    //take array index x milliseconds
          }, k * 500);
        }else  {
    //last word
          setTimeout(function()  {
    //display word into class
            $('.words').html(v);
    //take array index x milliseconds
    //show last word for a longer amount of time
          }, k * 1000);
        }
      });
      i++;
      if(i < lines.length)  {

    //if array is less than index, call again
        setTimeout(showLinesHelper(), 0);

      }
    }

    });
</script>

    <div class="words">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some changes to your code, I created a new variable **time** to keep a new count for the timeout and added a **-1** to the **IF** condition because the array length start at 0 and the **ELSE** was never hit it.

```js
$(function() {

//take sentence
  var lines = [
    'Apples are red',
    'Sky is blue',
    'Grass is green'
  ];
var i = 0;
var time = 1;
showLinesHelper();

function showLinesHelper()  {
//take line and split into words
  words = lines[i].split(' ');
  $.each(words, function(k, v)  {
//take each word and flash

    if(k != words.length - 1)  {
//if not last word

      setTimeout(function()  {
//display word into class
        $('.words').html(v);
//take array index x milliseconds
      }, time * 500);
      time = time + 2;
    }else  {
//last word

      setTimeout(function()  {
     
//display word into class
        $('.words').html(v);
//take array index x milliseconds
//show last word for a longer amount of time
      }, time * 500);
      time = time + 5;
    }
  });
  i++;
  if(i < lines.length)  {

//if array is less than index, call again
    setTimeout(showLinesHelper(), 0);

  }
}

});
```